# QtWebkit jquery ajax POST does not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, qt, webkit

I have QT webkit HTML5 application with one button which calls jQuery AJAX POST method

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#bntLogin').click(function(){
                var usrn = $('#txtUsername').val();
                var pwd = $('#txtPassword').val();

              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.ngg-l.com/Account/ClientLogin/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { username: usrn, password: pwd },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
               });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

xhr.status = 0

Does anyone knows why my ajax does not working?

Comment: From what page are you executing your script? Could it be forbidden since domains are different?

Comment: Yes domains is different

Comment: Then you should search for ways to perform cross-domain ajax request. I think that's your problem. To be sure, try issuing same request using browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
```

["Specifies whether locally loaded documents are allowed to access remote urls. This is disabled by default."](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebsettings.html)